# Strip commas, whitespace, periods from string in php

Tags: php, trim

Users submit names in two separate fields:
firstname(author_fname) and last name (author_lname)
Entries are sometimes Smith, John J.  or John and Mary Smith, or john j. smith.
I need to get all extraneous characters out of the submission, so the name comes up with just the words: smithjohnj or johnandmarysmith.
Using trim, I was able to delete the white space.

But I would like to get the comma out as well. Ex:

```
$text = $results["author_lname"].$results["author_fname"];
$trimmed = trim($text);
var_dump($trimmed);
$Aname = $trimmed;
```

Comment: trim only removes characters from the beginning and end of the string, not the middle. And without a second argument, it will only remove whitespace.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Thats what I thought. In looking at the manual, I see:
    string trim ( string $str [, string $character_mask = " \t\n\r\0\x0B" ] )
so would mine be: 
$text trim ( string $text [, string $character_mask = " ",. ] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you can use the php method: strtr as explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

In your case you could use strtr with your already trimmed string like this:

```
$stripped = strtr($trimmed, array(',' => ''));
```

This should do the trick.